# Create a custom cron job

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I need to create a routine that does the following tasks:

- Delete files in a specific folder that are more than 15 days of creation.
- Clear the cache folder daily
- Clean other specific folders also daily

I use [easycron.com](https://www.easycron.com/), therefore it's necessary that this routine is within the cron.php.

Comment: Just an idea, as your goal(s) are not defined in further detail: You do not necessarily need to write a Magento-Cronjob for this. You can achieve this with basic OS-commands (at least for Unix as I can speak) and execute them locally via cron on your webshop server.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to work with clearing folders based on a date I would suggest that this will be easier by using standard Unix commands, assuming that your system is unix based.

If you look into the function `find` you will see that you can specify the time of creation by the option `mtime`.

An example of this is:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +5
```

This will find files that are older than 5 days. You can then use the option `exec` to call a command on the files found. In your case you could call `rm` and that would remove the files. An example of this would be:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

**NOTE: be careful before you run anything that can remove files**